# Permutations and combinations on letters

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have given a few problems and i have been using the permutation and combination to solve the problems. However, i am suck at counting. but i do my best though. So, im here to ask a question.

how many permutations of the letters abcdef contain at least one of the patterns aeb or bef??

I have my own computation but it seems wrong.

I would like to know how you guys solve it. step by step. i have written down a formula and solved it. but my number came out really high which it seems wrong.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful for you to state your thought process and show your working.

Comment: too embrassed to show thats why my man

Comment: @jake : We are not here to humiliate you, we are here to help ; if you don't show us your work we can't tell you how you did wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: @jake I strongly echo Patrick. You learn a lot from explaining your work (even if it's wrong). An aspect of my site, is that I ask students to explain why they think my answer is wrong. In that process, many of them realize what their error is, and come to the correct solution.

Comment: i started off with 6!/(6-3)! and it's wrong. so i tried to solve it with differently. 2nd time i used 6!*2 and i think it's wrong. im lost.

Comment: That's a good start. You came close to it, with the ideas, but needed to be clearer. The idea of $6!/(6-3)!$ is that you wanted $6P3$. However, think about whether you have 3 items to permute, or 4. See Omnivium's answer to see why it is 4 items to permute, or why it is $4 \times 6 P3$.

Comment: how would you read 6P3 again? and i honestl dont understand why  4 times 6P3. i understand that it's 6P3 but 4 times?

Comment: Oops, the line "why it is $4 \times 6 P 3$" is a lie. Your idea of $6P3$ was good, thinking that out of 6 things, you had to choose 3 to permute. however, you didn't really have to choose 3 things, because they were already given (if we wanted a block of "aeb", then the free parts had to be c, d, f). Also, the block of "aeb" becomes 1 item, so we actually have 4 items now, namely aeb, c, d, f.

Answer (score 2):

In principle we list and count. The key fact is contained in the answer by Calvin Lin that the patterns aeb and bef cannot occur in the same word. So all we need to do is to count the words that have the pattern aeb, count the words that have the pattern bef, and add.

Life is made simpler by the fact that by symmetry there are just as many words with aeb as there are with bef. So we count the words with aeb and multiply by $2$.

We have $6$ "slots" $- - - - - -$ into which to put our letters. If our word is to contain aeb, the a can be put in any one of $4$ places. Then the locations of e and b are determined. For each of these $4$ choices, we are left with $3$ empty slots. The first empty slot can be filled in $3$ ways using letters chosen from c, d, f. For each of these ways, the second empty slot can be filled in $2$ ways, and now our word is determined. So there is a total of $(4)(3)(2)$ words that contain the pattern aeb.

Then double to get our final answer.

**Another way:** Think of "aeb" as a superletter, which we call S. Then the words that contain the string aeb are just the $4$-letter words made up of the "letters" c, d, f, and S. There are $4$ such "letters," so $4!$ such words. Now double like we did before.

Comment: I like the "superletter" answer!

Comment: just 4! *2?????

Comment: Yes, only $48$ of the $720$ permutations of the $6$ letters have the desired property.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Any permutation can contain at most 1 of the patterns, due to the placement of b and e.

Use the rule of sum.

Answer (score 0):

How many permutations contain $aeb$?  Well.  First notice that there are 4 possible ways for $aeb$ to occur.  $aebxxx, xaebxx, xxaebx, xxxaeb$, where the $x$ represent one of the other three letters.

Fix one of these four possibilities - how many ways can you arrange the remaining three letters?  Call that number $y$.  Then there are $4y$ possible permutations containing $aeb$.

The exact same reasoning gives you another $4y$ possible permutations containing $bef$.

As Calvin Lin pointed out, occurances of $aeb$ and $bef$ are mutually exclusive.  So add them up and you get...?

Comment: 4*3 times 4*3= 144?

Comment: Well, remember what you know about factorials.  The number of ways you can arrange $n$ letters is precisely $n!$, right?  So if you fix one of the possibilities I listed, you have $3!$ ways of filling out the remaining letters.  So the number $y$ in question is $6$, and your total is $4\cdot 6 + 4 \cdot 6 = 48$. The number is not really the important thing, but do you follow the reasoning?

Comment: Right, i clearly follow what you're saying. but i didnt follow that i have 3!  ways of filling out the remaining letters. i couldnt think of that

Comment: Right, well anytime you have 3 slots to fill with 3 distinct letters (letters, objects, whatever)... you have 3 choices for the first slot; then 2 choices for the second slot (since the first one is gone), and 1 choice for the last slot - so there's $3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 3!$ ways to do this.

Comment: whenever i see a problem like permuation, i automically think n! and for instance, 10*10*10*26*26*26 but if cannot be repeated then 10*9*8*26*25*24. i was able to solve basic problems but when i tried to solve this problem, i couldnt think other than 6!/(6-3)! and

Comment: The key is to not try to write down a formula right away.  Start thinking about the logic behind what you're being asked first, and then break it up into pieces.

Comment: @Omnivium WHAT DO YOU MEAN VIRGINIA?!

Comment: @Austin Mohr BAH, SUPER POOPER SCOOPERS ARE JUST LEGEND